# Glue databases exists but it's not visible in data catalog

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I stumbled upon a weird issue in AWS Glue service. I had created a database manually and then I deleted it. Now, when I try to again create database with the same name I get this:

[image]

However, there are no databases whatsoever:
[image]

Does anyone have an idea what the deal is?

Comment: It's really strange, it shouldn't work this way. Please contact AWS support, it will be hard to troubleshoot your problem without access to your AWS account. My only guess is that database exists on a different region

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @ColossalBoar, no I haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The account may have lake formation turned on, if so even an iam admin can't see the glue databases.  you have to go into lake formation console, administrative roles and tasks, and add your iam account as an admin.